# How can I get the correct case when calling Python's os.getcwd()?

Tags: python, macos

When I call os.getcwd() on my Mac under OS X 10.6.4 from my home directory, the path is converted to lowercase. I get

/users/myusername

instead of

/Users/myusername

On another Mac I get the correct uppercase string. How can I configure this? Is there a (hidden) Python setting?

Reason for asking:
On OS X all user directories are in "/Users". This is always uppercase. When using Mercurial, it gets sometimes confused with this strange and incorrect normalization of my current directory.

In reply to the suggested solutions:

(1)
DiskUtil says that my drive has a format of "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". I bought my computer some month ago and it's still the original drive, never reformatted.

(2) Another python console session log:

$>>> os.system('pwd')

/Users/klaas

0

$>>> os.getcwd()"

'/users/klaas'

$>>> os.path.normcase('/Users/klaas')

'/Users/klaas'

$>>> os.chdir('/UsErS/klaas')

$>>> os.getcwd()

'/users/klaas'

$>>> os.chdir('/UsErS/klaas')

$>>> os.getcwd()

'/users/klaas'

**Update 2:**

Thanks for all the replies. I created a test case in Objective-C and it has the same lowercase folder name:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);
```

Comment: Did you install another python (via `macports` or `fink`)? What version does Python report when you start it from the console? My system `Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29)  - [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin` works fine...

Comment: Are the hosts the same OS version and using the same filesystem?

Comment: Try running a script with os.getcwd using "dtruss". At least you can see what the OS returns for the directory.

Comment: Python reports Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 20:17:05) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin

Comment: Running with dtruss gives me stat64("/users/klaas\0", 0xBFFFED24, 0x87AC00)   = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x1, "'/users/klaas'\n\0", 0xF)   = 15 0

Comment: Both hosts have the same OS version (10.6.4 Build 10F569) and all updates installed.

Comment: So you know that it is *not* Python's problem. The OS itself returned a lower-case /users/klass.

Comment: yes, I traced it down, that you get the same lowercase result in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was an issue with the Mercurial installation. I ran into it again tonight.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download gives you different options how to install Mercurial. If I choose the first one (the Mac OS X packages) the "/Users" directory will be reported as "/users" (even when accessing it with Objective C). This can be solved by installing Mercurial via the macports option. This fixes the issue and the "/Users" directory is returned again with an uppercase "U".

Any hints why this is happening are still welcome.

But a least there is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The "HFS plus" filesystem, which has been Apple's filesystem of choice since the days of Mac OS 8, is normally not case-sensitive.

Mac OS X version 10.4, or "Tiger" as it's more commonly known, introduced the ability to create an HFS plus filesystem which is case-sensitive.

Could one of them be using a case-sensitive FS?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a problem with your particular Python install on your particular Mac. I haven't been able to turn up anyone else who has the same problem.

It's likely that your Mac has a problem with its installation of Python. AFAIK, there isn't a configuration option to make Python represent `getcwd()` with the proper case (this behavior should be enabled by default). If it's an option, I'd try reinstalling Python. If that doesn't work, you should report a bug to the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org).

Comment: A Python bug causing it to somehow lowercase the return value of `getcwd`?  That doesn't seem very likely--unless you actualy have evidence of this, suggesting to reinstall Python seems like throwing darts that are only going to waste his time.

Comment: @GlennMaynard it seems that he might have a problem with his Python install given that he can't reproduce the problem on another machine. It could be the filesystem, but I've encountered similar idiosyncracies with Python installs that were solved by reinstalling.

Comment: Even in the odd case where it is, he should be figuring out what's wrong so he can report a bug, not bulldozing over the problem and leaving it a mystery for the next person.  There is, however, nothing in Modules/posixmodule.c that modifies the result of `getcwd`.

Comment: I tried reinstalling with http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/python-2.7-macosx10.5.dmg , but the problem still persists. As someone else suggested I logged with dtruss and it seems that the OS returns the wrong case.

Answer (score 0):

Two uneducated guesses:

First, apparently OSX is usually case-insensitive, which usually means case-preserving: the name of the current directory either comes from how it's capitalized on disk, or how it was capitalized when you changed into it.  If you run `os.system('pwd')`, does it show it lowercased or not?  If so, then that's what the OS is reporting and Python isn't doing anything wrong.  Does it change if you `os.chdir('/UsErS/username')` first?

Second, there's one function that does lowercase or not selectively based on the OS: `os.path.normcase`.  The `macpath` version does lowercase.  I'm pretty sure `os.getcwd` does *not* automatically run the results through this; just mentioning it as a place to check.

Comment: ("Usually" because apparently HFS+ can be set to case-sensitive or not; I assume it ordinarily is.  http://bugs.python.org/issue3485.  Also, I don't know if "macpath" is for OSX or if it's lingering MacOS cruft; if it's the latter then that part is probably not relevant.)

Comment: Yeah, "macpath" is for MacOS; ignore that.

Comment: DiskUtil says that my drive has a format of "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". I bought my computer some month ago and it's still the original drive, never reformatted.

Comment: I tried your other suggestions as well:

>>> os.system('pwd')
/Users/klaas
0
>>> os.getcwd()
'/users/klaas'
>>> os.path.normcase('/Users/klaas')
'/Users/klaas'
>>> os.chdir('/UsErS/klaas')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/users/klaas'

Comment: I don't know; at this point I'd compile the Python source with debugging and trace the `getcwd` call to see what's going on.  I just don't see anything in there that could lowercase the result.